# Java Clock Applet

Tags: java, date, applet, awt

I have a java applet that displays the current date and time and updates automatically each second. It is essentially a live clock. It is showing the date and time in it's default format (which looks like this: `Mon Oct 27 15:10:13 CDT 2014`), but I would like to switch it up a little bit and have it displayed something like this: `Mon 10/27/2014 15:10:13 CDT`.

I took a look at some past questions on here and used what I found to update my code, but it no longer displays the time at all, so I'm doing something wrong. Here was my original function followed by the modified, non-working function:

Original function:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawString(new java.util.Date().toString(), 10, 30);

}
```

Modified, non-working function:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawString(new java.util.Date("E MM/dd/yyyy k:m:s z").toString(), 10, 30);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new java.util.Date("E MM/dd/yyyy k:m:s z")
```

This doesn't seem to compile at all for me and seems to be the source of your problem:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at java.util.Date.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Date.<init>(Unknown Source)
at Test.main(Test.java:4)
```

Instead, I would use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E MM/dd/yyyy k:m:s z");
g.drawString(sdf.format(new Date()), 10, 30);
```

Comment: I tried swapping in your code and I got errors: SimpleDateFormat cannot be resolved to a type
 SimpleDateFormat cannot be resolved to a type
 Date cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: @Brett You need to use the import statements for them. `import java.util.Date;` and `import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;` Your IDE, if you're using one, will prompt you for the import. Date has several, so you have to explicitly find the `util` version, but SDF is unique.

Answer (score 2):

1. Call `super.paint` before doing any kind of custom painting.
2. Consider using a label of some kind to display text instead of custom painting
3. Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to change the format the `Date` object.

You could use something along the lines of...

```
protected static final SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss z");

//...

String dateString = SDF.format(new Date());
//... Paint away
```